# Does the category of schemes have fibered coproducts?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The category of schemes has coproducts, but does it have arbitrary fiber coproducts?

Comment: No. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9961/colimits-of-schemes

Incidentally, "fiber coproduct" is a terrible name for a pushout, since pushouts have nothing to do with fibers, whereas in a pullback/fiber product, you are literally taking the products of the corresponding fibers. At best it would be reasonable, but ungainly, to say "co-(fiber product)."

Comment: I always enjoyed the name *amalgamated sum*, but I usually just say "pushout"